# Switch from Xorg to Wayland on Ubuntu Studio 18.04

Tags: xorg, 18.04, wayland

How can you switch from Xorg to Wayland in Ubuntu Studio 18.04. I need to recover the resolution of my 2560 x 1440 monitors that Ubuntu Studio 17.10 gave me and Xorg does not allow me to do that.

Comment: On logging screen you can choose like described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: In Ubuntu Studio 18.04 there is no gear at the start there is only in the shuttle the option to start under Xfce or as Ubuntu Studio, so I think they have eliminated the option to configure Wayland