# 'LeftShift+RightShift' switches layout although it's not configured to

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, keyboard-layout

I have new Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.1 on my laptop, and I run into a problem.

I have set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on keyboard layout switching, but <kbd>LeftShift</kbd>+<kbd>RightShift</kbd> combo also triggers the switching, and I just can't find out why.

I have used `gnome-tweak-tool` for the configuring, and I can guarantee that there is no ticks on the checkbox `Both Shifts together`. As for built-in `Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Typing`, they have been set to `Disabled` and therefore can't interfere.

Also, I checked `org/gnome/desktop/input-sources` via `dconf-editor`, and it shows `grp:alt_shift_toggle` as it should, there is no mention of `grp:shifts_toggle` at all. But it still switches a layout, and it just makes me mad. Can anyone help me? Is it a bug or something?

P.S. However, if I disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> as a layout-switcher, <kbd>LeftShift</kbd>+<kbd>RightShift</kbd> also disappears, so it seems `grp:shifts_toggle` is a sort of "backup value" or "repeater" of `grp:alt_shift_toggle`.

P.P.S There are some links where people had encountered with the same, but  no solution was found.

https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/73k5lq/why_pressing_leftshiftrightshift_changes_keyboard/

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174715

Comment: I see the same. But how is it a problem? I suppose that you rarely press both the shift keys accidentally. Anyway, maybe the `grp:lalt_lshift_toggle` option is what you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, but `LeftAlt+LeftShift` is only a half-way solution. It really disables `LeftShit+RightShift`, but `RightShift+LeftShift` still switches the layout, which is unwanted behaviour too.

Comment: As for the rarity, it's not very uncommon to press both shifts together, if you do fast 10-fingers touch typing. You see, if you type something in capital letters, and don't use `CapsLock` for it (as i do for single capital words), you will need to alternate between `LeftShift` and `RightShift` very fast, depending on which letter key you need to press right now. And sometimes, `RightShift` is not unpressed yet, while `LeftShift` is already pressed, causing layout switching in the middle of word you trying to type.

Comment: <Super>+<Space> is the default shortcut for switching input source. Maybe try that then?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't disable the <kbd>LeftShift</kbd>+<kbd>RightShift</kbd> shortcut anywhere, and at the end I decided to switch to Wayland as a replacement to Xorg. If you are using GNOME3 with GDM, change GDM settings in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, and choose Wayland instead of Xorg.

Comment: Someone should clarify this answer. The missing detail for GDM settings may be the reverse of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/37165), which I am not sure since I do not use GNOME.

Comment: Nevermind, this answer is wrong, I thought it actually fixed the issue, but then realized it didn't. Apparently pressing RShift first then press LShift (while holding RShift) will switch the layout, while the reverse will not (LShift then RShift). I still can't figure out how to prevent this combo from changing the layout