# All LibreOffice windows are in one menu icon

Tags: icons, libreoffice, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 18.04 using GNOME, all of the opened LibreOffice windows are concentrated under one LibreOffice menu icon.

This is unlike the former versions where each application (Writer, Calc ...) had its own icon. This is very uncomfortable when you have many windows opened.

Is there any way to change this setting?

Comment: This is not standard behaviour. Also in Ubuntu 18.04, different components of LO have a different icon. Is your installation a standard fresh install? Beware that, as a bug, it may take up to 30 seconds before the icon of another LO component actually appears in Alt+tab (or the Dash if not pinned).

Comment: Are you by any chance in a Wayland session? What's the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: I do have different icons for each component, but it only opens new files. All of the existing files are under the LibreOffice icon.

Comment: Yes, I was under Wayland session. Logging back to normal session solved the problem.

Comment: It depends... if you install from PPA, you will have separate icons... installing from web page (deb files), you will have one icon in case of installing the development version...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with LibreOffice in a Wayland session (see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1727958) and [this](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100158)). You can verify whether you're in a Wayland session by running

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

As a workaround you may [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10). Then the icons should appear correctly.