# Ubuntu 19.10 (Wayland session) doesn't screen record

Tags: 19.10, wayland, desktop-recording

After upgrading from 18.04.3 (in which I could screen record with 3rd party apps with ease) to 19.10, I'm unable to screen record with any 3rd party provider; only the default GNOME shell screen recorder extension works. OBS Studio, Kazam even Vokoscreen don't record the screen. If I click on record, it shows that it is recording but when I take a look at the saved screencast, I can only see the cursor  moving against a black background. However if I try screen recording in an XOrg session, it works just fine.
Here is an example of what I'm on about; take a look at the link: [An example of how my screen is recorded](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xbGQRwv2QeTxZF-HiaWI0Ioy9Yc4YRiZ)

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: switching to Xorg may solve it, if you consider doing so.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10