# PuTTY: "unable to load font" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fonts, remote, putty

I have installed PuTTY on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS . When I enter the IP address and click on the **Open** button, Putty gets closed automatically.

The error message is:

> PuTTY: unable to load font "server:fixed

Comment: As a workaround, select a different font in the Window/Fonts settings.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem today. So I tried to change the font, which you can see on left middle side of PuTTY. Go to **Fonts** and change it for  **Font use for ordinary text**; set it according to your choice. I set it to *UBUNTU MONO*. It worked.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is caused because of font default setting.
From the Left menu: Categor --> window --> Fonts --> Fonts Used for ordinary text.
change the default font from server:fixed to your desired font family.
but this is not permanent. you can fix this problem permanently by editing the file in this path:
~/.putty/sessions/Default%20Settings

change The "FontName" value to your desired font.
this should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Run Putty from shortcut or from shell this way:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 putty
```

**You need to set variable exactly with env `env GDK_BACKEND=x11`, without `env` it will not work (for Putty at least)**

Found here:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326331/where-to-set-gdk-backend
- https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/putty/pull-request/3

It turns out that it is happening because of running Putty from Wayland. Maybe Wayland doesn't have that font family or something. Sadly I can't say more.

Maybe running the app like this can help with other apps? Can someone try it? Because I don't know whether that will be helpful to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. I am on WSL2 and tried many solutions without luck before I saw this.
I just added

```
EXPORT GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

to my .bashrc and now putty works great.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241265)