# Install PuTTY ver 0.76 on Ubuntu 20.04 & comms to ESP32

Tags: 20.04, usb, fonts, putty

I have installed Putty 0.73 on Ubuntu 20.04. I've followed the `esp32 esp-idf` instructions found [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html): . (`sudo apt install putty`, etc.) My purpose is to get comms working between the laptop and an **ESP32 WROOM module**, flash and run hello_world and move on from there. (Following the steps, `/dev/ttyUSB0` shows up when I plug in the USB cable to the ESP32.)

After installing and running Putty, I get the terminal error message:

```
(putty:4202): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 07:35:52.031: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar.
```

The installed version of `Putty is 0.73`, which is documented to have this bug. The terminal doesn't return to a command prompt but loads the GUI. I've tried the suggestion from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255916/putty-unable-to-load-font-in-ubuntu-20-04.) It doesn't work as I cannot save anything from the GUI interface.

I have installed Putty 0.73 on Ubuntu 20.04. I've followed the esp32 esp-idf instructions found [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html): After installing and running Putty, I get the terminal error message:

```
(putty:4202): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 07:35:52.031: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar.
```

The installed version of `Putty is 0.73`, which is documented to have this bug. The terminal doesn't return to a command prompt but loads the GUI.

The Putty GUI also displays, and I'm able to change settings including setting the font to Ubuntu, changing serial values, etc. When I then click OPEN it just beeps.
Ver 0.74... is noted to address this. The latest ver of Putty is 0.76, which I'd like to install and hopefully fix the problem.

I'm unable to find how to install Ver 0.76. The download is available  [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) but the only Unix download is "Unix source archive", `.tar.gz`, `putty-0.76.tar.gz`.

The Putty GUI also displays, and I'm able to change settings including setting the font to Unbutu, changing serial values, etc. When I then click OPEN it just beeps.

Ver 0.74... is noted to address this. The latest ver of Putty is 0.76, which I'd like to install and hopefully fix the problem.

I'm unable to find how to install Ver 0.76. The download is available at [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) but the only Unix download is "Unix source archive", `.tar.gz:`, `putty-0.76.tar.gz`.

Can anyone suggest how to install ver 0.76 or any other approach to establish comms? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can install putty 0.74 from the Ubuntu 21.04 archive.

Download `putty`:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/putty/download

and `putty-tools`:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/putty-tools/download

Then navigate to the `~/Downloads` directory and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i putty*
```

Possibly you can pick putty 0.75 from Ubuntu impish instead, but I haven't confirmed that that version is installable on 20.04.

Comment: Hi. I installed 21.04, which enabled me to install Putty 0.74. I still get same or similar error terminal messages as noted in my original post. The GUI loads, but I have the same problems noted above - can't click OK. Can only cancel out of the screen.

Comment: @pwl: Ok. It may then be worth it to try downloading and installing 0.75 from impish.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get serial working and you can't get putty working, there are several other communication tools that support serial ports.  Here's a short list of native ubuntu serial tools:

- minicom
- screen

Comment: I previously installed minicom, with it hanging while trying to establish comms. After the upgrade to 21.04, I was able to have minicom reply to the command: ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0 with the response: "CRW-RW-----