# XP-pen not working on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: 21.10, stylus

When I was on Ubuntu 21.04, I used my XP-pen stylus with tablet on Krita with no problem.

I just completed the upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10, I am discovering that my XP-pen stylus shows the cursor but stop writing/drawing.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the Wayland session? Switch to the XOrg session and check again.

Comment: Try this. https://askubuntu.com/a/961345/124466

Comment: Yes, it works. So 21.04 was de facto on XOrg session?

Comment: No, 21.04 also used Wayland by default, and such issues were frequent. You might have switched to X.Org in 21.04 at some point/upgraded from a previous version which used X.Org/were using a Wayland version that was compatible with your tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.10 uses Wayland by default. However, Wayland is still not fully ready, and many things like screen sharing, pen-tablets do not work out of the box. The workaround is to use the X.Org session in the login screen.

In your login screen, you can switch to the "Ubuntu" session, which uses X.Org, and it should allow screen recording software to function properly.

[image]
 <sup>Image source: [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default)</sup>