# Ibus anthy and ibus mozc don't seem to work on either firefox and chrome in 22.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ibus, 22.04, mozc

I'm on a clean installation of ubuntu 22.04. I've successively tried mozc and anthy, and they both worked in every application I've tested except for firefox. I then tested on chrome, and they don't seem to work either on it. (Instead of typing japanese characters, it just types latin characters as if nothing had happened)

If someone have a fix or at least an explication, I'd be grateful for it

**--- Edit :**

I uninstalled the snap release of firefox and **switched to the apt release** instead (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04), and it fixed the problem for me. However, it still doesn't seem to work on chrome, which is weird since it was installed through apt.

It's not much of a problem for me since I don't use it, but I'd rather mention it.

Answer (score 1):

What about set:

```bash
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```

You can add these lines to file such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, etc.

Then log in your system again to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have an exact same thing except **Wayland Off** and I can type it on Google Chrome and Firefox (apt edition).

[image: Select_Hiragana]

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/656190) answer, I turned Wayland off

`/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

`WaylandEnable=false`

Comment: Well disabling Wayland led, for me, to mozc not even working on the applications where it used to. But using the apt edition of firefox instead of snap solved the problem, at least within firefox

Comment: If you can abandon `ibus` and use `fcitx-mozc` no more problems.