# Skype and screen sharing

Tags: skype

Last time I decided to use Ubuntu 17.10. When I installed Skype from official site of Skype (I downloaded the `.deb` package) I can do almost everything without one important feature for me. I can't share my screen while I am talking with somebody. On Windows that was working perfectly, on Ubuntu I don't even see such a option.

My friend has *the same* version of Ubuntu, GNOME and Skype. He can use that feature. I can't and I can't figure out why.

Comment: My friend has THE SAME version of ubuntu, gnome and skype. He can use that feature. I can't and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use Wayland (Ubuntu 17.10) and latest version (v8.11.0.4) of skypeforlinux screen sharing is not working.

In order to have screen sharing working you can switch to Xorg as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Otherwise you can use Google Hangout, where you can even share windows.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for help. I changed Wayland to Xorg and it works perfect.

Answer (score 9):

This is because ubuntu 17.10 switched from Xorg display server to wayland.([Why wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better)). But many applications are yet to port to wayland. many of the existing applications do not work properly with wayland. Skype is also such a case.

To switch from wayland to Xorg (X11). Do the following

- Log out from the current session
- then select Ubuntu on Xorg from the login screen
  [image]
- Make sure you have an X11 Session by executing the following command in terminal.

  `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

it should output `x11`

**now your Skype screen sharing will work**

Answer (score 7):

The latest version(s) (v8.x.x.x onwards) of `skypeforlinux` (`.deb` package downloaded from Skype website) has the screen-sharing option (only in an Xorg session, if you're in a default Wayland session you'll have to [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) first).

You can access this option by clicking on the **+** symbol (More Options) at the bottom while making a video call:

[image]

Comment: Version Skype'a 8.11.0.4
Version of module speach 2017.23.01.38

And I don't see any share screen...

Edit: Gnome 3.26.1 Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Key part for me was, that you need to make a *video call* before this option is available. In other words: If you don't have a webcam you can't share your screen. I have no idea who's responsible for this IMO stupid decision at Microsoft :(.

Comment: I'm using Skypeforlinux on Ubuntu 19.10 on an Xorg session and still I don't have any share screen option.

Comment: Yeah, 2 years later... Ubuntu 19.10. XOrg or Wayland - screen sharing is greyed out in conf. calls

Answer (score 1):

You can use web skype (web.skype.com). Enter skype web site and login to skype from the web it is exactly like the app and everything works normally there.
Note: It works on chrome for now.

Comment: It works normally if you're in an Xorg session. The problem was different, Ubuntu 17.10 came with Wayland as the default instead of Xorg. Screen sharing doesn't work on Wayland due to its security restrictions.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18. Web.skype solved sharing problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, because Ubuntu 18.04 and later releases comes with Xorg as the default session instead on Wayland. Read this: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/xorg-will-default-display-server-ubuntu-18-04-lts